# Complex analysis,Functional analysis for deeper understanding Machine Learning.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, machine-learning, advice

I want to get deeper into the Machine Learning(theory and application in Finance).
I want to ask how relevant are **complex analysis** and **functional analysis** as a basis for Machine Learning? Do I need to learn these subjects or should I concentrate myself on other topich(if so, on which?)

Comment: You might want to try asking this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't think complex analysis or functional analysis are very relevant for Machine Learning. (Bayesian) statistics, probability and Convex (and non-convex) optimization seem to me like essential pillars as well as a good grasp of standard tools of mathematics such as linear algebra. If you want to look at applications for finance you may also be interested in signal processing.

Comment: for references http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236958/complex-analysis-functional-analysis-for-deeper-understanding-machine-learning